# Mobile js navbar issue

Tags: javascript

I'm currently looking at the most simple, maybe efficient, way of writing code for the mobile perspective.

Here's what I'm currently looking at but need a little bit of hep with.

```
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

The code above isn't working, what are the solutions please?

Comment: Please provide more context, what isn't working?

Comment: When I click the icon, burger, menu, it doesn't display the list items when in mobile media queries.